# How do I rename a Shared Photo Stream?

Tags: ios, icloud, photo-stream

The only option in my Shared Photo Stream appears to be "Edit", which lets me add/delete photos. Can I rename the title perhaps online somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back one screen to the main Photo Stream screen. From there, tap on the blue arrow for the Shared Photo Stream you want to change, and you can edit the name, subscribers, etc.

Main screen showing the blue arrow on the right:

[image]

Sub-screen after tapping on the Photo Stream I want to modify:

[image]

Comment: Just a note that this is out-of-date now with iOS 7 & 8. Correct method now is:

iCloud Photo Sharing -> Edit (top right) -> tap on album name text from listing -> Make edits & hit Done

Comment: @nickb please post this as an answer:)

Comment: @DanielGalasko Done!

Answer (score 6):

New method for iOS 7, 8, and 9:

- Open the **Photos** app
- Make sure you're on the **iCloud Photo Sharing** screen (tap **back** as necessary)
- Hit **Edit** (top right)
- Tap on album name text from listing
- Make your edits
- Tap **Done** to save